# Maven on the empty project downloads tons of dependencies

Tags: maven

I use Maven on daily basis in my work for more then 5 years. But I never tried to test the minimum dependencies project.

So I created a new directory on my disk and put inside a `pom.xml` file. It is the most simple pom file you can create. It contains only this:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.jikra</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</project>
```

And that's it. There is nothing more. No other directories, not a single Java file, nothing.

Then I cleared my local repository and ran `mvn clean install` in the folder with my pom file.

Maven downloaded tons of dependencies I don't need. My project is empty, there is only one pom file. Yet, there are more then 7,6M of files in my local repository, now.

I'm not any kind of Maven master, so I wonder why all those dependencies are necessary. Does anyone know?

Comment: All plugins which are used during your build...which are not the same versions as you might used by other builds before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project has some [predefined plugins declared](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob_plain;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml;hb=HEAD) as well as `packaging` (default is `jar`) [which defines](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml) a list of additional plugins as well as their bindings. Those are getting downloaded along with their transitive dependencies.

You can run `mvn help:effective-pom` in order to see what's *actually* present in your project.

You could also see plugins and their dependencies with: `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`